# Is there a keyboard shortcut for listing object members in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual studio .net text editor (not VSCode), there's a short-cut "List members - Ctrl+J [Text Editor, Workflow Designer] Edit.ListMembers - [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019%22).

Now i'm doing typescript in VSCode, just wonder if there is something equivalent. Deleting the member in the editor then type "." again can do the job, but it's great if there is a short-cut for that.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out you can do that with ctrl+space - https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/intellisense#_intellisense-features

Comment: For people who are using more than 1 keyboard layout on `macos`, user `fn/globe + control + space` to show the properties, as doing only `control + space` , conflicts with the default macos switch keybaord layout shortcut.